# How can I replace a character in a specific column?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, tr

How can I change the date setting from 24/05/2016 to 24.05.2016?

```
24/05/2016 |  15:31:38 | Run    | Spotify Web Helper          | "C:\Users\evild3ad\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\SpotifyWebHelper.exe"
24/05/2016 |  15:31:38 | Run    | CCleaner Monitoring         | "C:\Program Files\CCleaner\CCleaner64.exe" /MONITOR             
24/05/2016 |  15:31:38 | Run    | DAEMON Tools Lite Automount | "C:\Program Files\DAEMON Tools Lite\DTAgent.exe" -autorun
```

I tried: cat source.txt | tr '/' '.'

The problem is, that source.txt has also the '/' character in the last column. Is it possible to change the character '/' only in column $1?
Thanks in advance for you help!

Edit:
I tried:

```
awk '{gsub("/",".",$1)}1' --> destroys format
awk -F\| '{gsub(/\//,".",$1); print}' --> format okay, but the delimiter '|' is gone.
```

Comment: Ugly here, but you can use `sed 's#\([^/]*\)/\([^/]*\)/#\1-\2-#' source.txt`.

Comment: Thanks Walter! I changed it to: sed 's#\([^/]*\)/\([^/]*\)/#\1.\2.#'